# How to push Shopify info into firebase database?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, shopify

I've been assigned a project where I'm making a react native app that's supposed to be the mobile app of a Shopify website, I have full access to Shopify admin but I'm having trouble getting all the product info from Shopify

I've tried shopify-api-node library but it has to run on a backend server and firebase cloud functions is giving me functions did not deploy properly error

```
admin.initializeApp()

const shopify = new Shopify({
    shopName: 'name',
    apiKey: 'key',
    password: 'password'
})

shopify.product.list({limit: 250})
.then(product => array.push(product))
.catch(() => {})

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.data = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin.database().ref('/test').push({array})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to call the Shopify API **inside** of your `exports.data` Cloud Function. Something like this:

```
exports.data = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  shopify.product.list({limit: 250})
    .then(product => {
      return admin.database().ref('/test').push(product)
    }).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send('ok')
    });
})
```

Comment: gives me this error when i do that: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1

Comment: I added some code to send a response to the caller. If that doesn't solve it, add the complete, exact error message you get. I'd also recommend taking a Cloud Functions tutorial, such as this one: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/

Comment: Gives me the same error and the tutorial isn't helping very much either, thanks for taking the time to reply anyways

Comment: "If that doesn't solve it, add the complete, exact error message you get."

Comment: I added the shopify-api-node library to the package.json of the functions folder, but now i get a browser error "Error: could not handle the request" when i click the link in the logs, also no data gets pushed to database